# Wildcard expression in SQL Server

Tags: regex, t-sql, sql-server-2012, wildcard

I know that, the following query returns the rows, which are contain the exact 5 characters between the `A` and `G`

```
select * 
from 
     (select 'prefixABBBBBGsuffix' code /*this will be returned. */
      union 
      select 'prefixABBBBGsuffix') rex 
where 
     code like '%A_____G%'
```

But I want 17 character between `A` and `G`, then `like` condition must have 17 underscores. So I search little in google I found `[]` will be used in like. Then I  tried so for.

```
select * 
from 
    (select 'AprefixABBBBBGsuffixG' code 
     union 
     select 'AprefixABBBBGsuffixG') rex 
where 
    code like '%A[_]^17G%' /*As per my understanding, '[]' makes a set. And  
                               '^17' would be power of the set (like Mathematics).*/
```

Then it returns the NULL set. How can I search rows which has certain number of character in the set `[]`?

**Note:**

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: sql server doesn't support full regex.

Comment: in sql, [] can make a set, like [A-Za-z] which matches exactly one alphabet char upper and lower case, but when used with _ it's an escape. example, like '%5[%]' will match any string ending in 5% and [_] means a literal _ and []] means a literal ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same answer as previously but corrected. 17 wasn't the number, it was 18 and 19 for strings, also put in the len(textbetweenA and G) to show.

```
select rex.* 
from (
    select len('prefixABBBBBGsuffix') leng, 'AprefixABBBBBGsuffixG' code 
    union 
    select len('prefixABBBBGsuffix'), 'AprefixABBBBGsuffixG'
    union
    select 0, 'A___________________G'
    ) rex 
where 
    rex.code like '%A' + replicate('_',19) + 'G%'

--and with [] the set would be [A-Za-z]. Notice this set does not match the A___________________G string.

select rex.* 
from (
    select len('prefixABBBBBGsuffix') leng, 'AprefixABBBBBGsuffixG' code 
    union 
    select len('prefixABBBBGsuffix'), 'AprefixABBBBGsuffixG'
    union
    select 0, 'A___________________G'
    ) rex 
where 
    rex.code like '%A' + replicate('[A-Za-z]',19) + 'G%'
```

[A-Za-z0-9] matches **one** character within the scope of alphabet (both cases) or a number 0 through 9

I can't find any working information about another way to handle a number of chars like that, replicate is just a way to ease parameterization and typing.

Comment: It gives the exact answer, even I was added some data like `union select 'A'+REPLICATE ('_',17)+'G' `

Comment: But I cant understood, why `19` was passed? I want 17 character. So my where clause as `rex.code like '%A' + replicate('[A-Za-z]',17) + 'G%'`

Comment: neither of the original examples with A and G on the ends had 17 chars between, one had 18 and one had 19. so I chose one of those numbers to show in the example. remove the extra character(s) and you can get 17 :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `REPLICATE` to generate desired number of '_':

```
select * from (
  select 'prefixABBBBBGsuffix' code 
  union 
  select 'prefixABBBBGsuffix'  
) rex 
where code like '%A' + REPLICATE('_',17) + 'G%';
```

Comment: Thanks for response. `union select 'A'+REPLICATE ('_',17)+'G'` if I add this, it will be returned. So I go with @JBJ answer.